# How to redirect action="phpmailer.php" depending on form data?

Tags: javascript, php, html

We have a HTML formular with different data. Name, E-Mail and a dropdown.
Method is POST and the form data is submitted via PHP.
Also a "thank-you" site is configurated. Works well.

Now we need for each selected dropdown a different landing-page redirect.
Lets say the dropdown contains "yellow", "black" and "green".

Onclick Submit should send the data and redirect to the correct thank-you site (html site).

- thanks-for-purchasing-green-color.html
- thanks-for-purchasing-black-color.html
- thanks-for-purchasing-yellow-color.html

is there a simple method? we are open also or non-php solutions.

i hope it's clear what we are looking for.

best regards

Comment: Concat your path with the value got in php and redirect to that url

Answer (score 2):

you can add the color as a value in every `option`

```
<select name="color">
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

after that when you receive it in your backend you will make redirect depending on the value of your select value by concatenating the color with the full age name

```
$page = "thanks-for-purchasing-".$_POST['color']."-color.html"
header('location:'.$page);
```